# How can I execute bash command line in Exec resource type?

Tags: puppet

I have this Exec declaration:

```
    exec { 'Normalize MP3 filename':
            environment => ["t=0"],
            command => 'for i in *mp3; do  mv -v $i track_`seq -f "%03g" $t $t`.mp3 ; t=`expr $t + 1`; done',
            cwd     => "$resource_path/res/raw",
    } ->
```

When my manifest runs it get this error:

```
Error: Could not find command 'for'
Error: /Stage[main]/Make_it::App_mp3files/Exec[Normalize MP3 filename]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Could not find command 'for'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default exec provider on *nix OSes is `posix`, which [does not support shell built-ins such as `for`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#exec-providers). You should change the provider to `shell` to use shell built-ins.

```
exec { 'Normalize MP3 filename':
        environment => ["t=0"],
        command => 'for i in *mp3; do  mv -v $i track_`seq -f "%03g" $t $t`.mp3 ; t=`expr $t + 1`; done',
        cwd     => "$resource_path/res/raw",
        provider => 'shell',
} ->
```